# Yii2 make session works on all actions of one controller?

Tags: yii2

In my SiteContoller I need to access the session on almost every action.
but I find write

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->open();
```

duplicate the same code on every action of the same controller is annoying.
anyway to solve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your session opened in only `SiteContoller` you need to open it in before action method as so:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    Yii::$app->session->open();
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: and now the method is not called isStarted(), it's called isActive();

Comment: @tyan yes, my bad I am sorry, I have mixed up with yii1.1. Seems yii2 makes necessary check before opening the session. Try to add `beforeAction` method in your controller.

Comment: @tyan by the way, resources say that session in yii2 is started automatically when it is needed, means when you try to get session values using NOTE yii components it starts the session.

Comment: i don't know why, the auto start not work in my situation, But open it in the beforeAction works well.

Comment: @tyan `autoStart` was removed in yii2, I messed version 2 with 1.1. In yii2 the session starts automatically as soon as you try to use it like `Yii::$app->session->get('some_key')` or `Yii::$app->user->getState('is_admin')`